# different versions of abcpdf on the same server

Tags: visual-studio-2010, abcpdf

I have two versions of abcpdf running on the same machine. One of the projects is using the older version 7.1 and the other one is using the newer version i.e 8.1.

When i try to build, the visual studio automatically picks up the latest version on abcpdf 8.1 and throws the following compile error

```
'WebSupergoo.ABCpdf7.Doc.Doc()' is obsolete: 'Don't use ABCpdf7 namespace - use ABCpdf8 instead.'
```

Please suggest me where i am going wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uninstall both versions from the GAC, and re-start IIS to get them cleared out.

Then reference the specific dlls from your projects manually, following the instructions for a manual install:

http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdf5net/source/3-concepts/6-installation.htm

You will need to point your project references to the two different AbcPdf.dll files (one for each version), and you will need to make sure that either ABCpdfCE7.dll or ABCpdf8-32(or -64).dll is copied to the bin of the correct project.